# How to store backups in GDrive as WhatsApp does its all chats and also the images and videos with it

Tags: android, google-drive-api, drive

[I need to store data like this in users Gdrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FmAq.png)

I have tried checking out the docs of GDrive Apis the closest something i have found is Storing App Specific Data in GDrive.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata

But the docs are really unclear and feels really outdated.